# How can I draw a circular arc with three points in a StreamGeometry

Tags: wpf, geometry

I'm using a `StreamGeometry` object to create an complete figure. The figure is a series of lines and arcs. The arcs are all circular defined by a start point, end point, and a <strike>middle</strike> point that the arc also passes through. How can I convert that into what `ArcTo` requires. I've been searching for a solution all morning. I will try to work the math out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Find radius of circle with plain geometry

Let's A, B, C - three points given (B is middle point of arc), M is middle point of AC chord, then 
[image]

`AM * CM = BM * B'M`, where B' is point at another end of circle diameter, due to "intersecting chords theorem".

`AM=CM=AC/2, BM+B'M = 2R`, so we can find circle radius R

```
(2R-BM) * BM = AM^2
2R-BM = AM^2/BM
R = (BM^2+AM^2)/(2*BM)
```

2) Now it is possible to find circle center with vector geometry

**O** = **B** + **uBM** * R, where **uBM** = **BM**/|**BM**| is unit vector

3) size parameter of ArcTo set to (R, R)

4) rotationAngle set to atan2(**OA** x **OC**, **OA** * **OC**) (crossproduct and scalar product of OA and OC vectors)

5) set the rest of ArcTo parameters as needed

Comment: OK, then use more complicated methods (for example, eq. 28-34 here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle.html)

Comment: Yeah, thank. I did the math myself. I was just wondering if anyone had a library or a quick formula so I wouldn't have to waste time figuring it out.